# How can I hide a dev studio toolbar in debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, menu, toolbar

When I debug in DevStudio, I get extra debug centric toolbars that appear which is great.

I would also like to turn off one or more of the standard toolbars since I don't need them in debug mode. Is this possible?

I've tried removing them whilst debugging, but they remain unavailable once I finish debugging.

**EDIT**: I was trying to hide the Test Tools toolbar, but I have just tried hiding the Text Editor toolbar and get exactly the same behaviour. Removing whilst in debug results in removed in design mode.

The only non-standard thing I can think I'm running is VS10 Power Tools, but I'm not aware of anything that does with toolbars.

Comment: What version are you using?  There is do modes: debugging and not debugging.  Each has their own layout.  changing the layout in one more should not change the layout in another.

Comment: RE Test Tools toolbar.  I tried enabling the Test Tools toolbar in Debug mode and when I switched to non-debug mode the toolbar went away.  I'm also using VS10 Productivity PowerTools.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said, the two layouts are independent. If you hide a toolbar in debug mode and show it in design mode the two states should remain as you set them.  If not you would need to indicate what toolbars in specificwe are talking about to make sure the owners aren't doing something questionable like force synchronizing their visibility across all layouts.